# How to pick latest Date in Created_at column in MySQL for Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have three database tables in my Laravel project **(Borrowers, Savings, Savings_Transaction )**. My aim is to show dormant accounts that have not had any Savings Transaction for the past 30 days.

In my borrowers' table, I have columns like

1. id
2. first_name
3. last_name

[image: Borrowers Table]

In My  Savings table, I have

1. id (auto_incremenent)
2. Borrower_id (picking id for borrowers table)

[image: Savings Table]

In my Savings_transaction table, I have

1. id (auto_incremenent)
2. savings_id (picking id from savings table)
3. Borrower_id (picking id from borrower_table)
4. Created_at (the date on which transaction is recorded)

[image: Savings_transactions Table]

Each borrower has A savings account which is recorded in  Savings table. And whenever they make a transaction it's recorded in the savings_transaction table.

In  Every trasanction borrower_id, savings_id, and created_at are recorded.

Now I would like to select borrowers who have not carried out any transaction for the past 30 days (Dormant Accounts /Members)  using this code

```
public function dormant()
{



        $dormant = SavingTransaction::where('reversed', 0)->where('branch_id',
            session('branch_id'))->whereDate('created_at','<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))->groupBy('savings_id','created_at')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();


    return view('saving.dormant',
        compact('dormant'));
}
```

but it's bringing all accounts having transactions with the date below 30 days and those above

**How do I remove accounts with the latest transactions ?**

Comment: Could you please add the tables as text not images see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: why selecting SavingTransaction if you want Borrowers?

Comment: @SergioDonati because am looking for an account without any savings_transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I would like to select borrowers who have not carried out any transaction for the past 30 days

You have to select Borrowers and not SavingTransaction

```php
// suppose "savingTransactions" is hasMany relation defined in Borrowers model
$result = Borrowers::whereDoesntHave('savingTransactions', function($queryBuilder){
  $queryBuilder->whereDate('created_at','<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30));
})->get();
```

If you not have the relation, you can also use `->whereNotExists(...)`